# JSF how to split forms

Tags: html, forms, jsf

is it possible to "split" a form?

e.g. i have two forms which would collide (one row of a table needs to stay in form 1, the other in form 2 and so on)

so i need a technique to make this possible like in HTML5 (form="formid")
[image]

all black fields must be the same form (content)
and all red fields are also one form together (actions for submit)

I need to be able to access both of them individually, they are just positined like the picture above. unfortunately I cannot make a form of a specific shape which includes some components and others not.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do that? Using ajax you can do form partial processing, but doing what you ask makes no sense for me (various forms for a single component). Have you thought about using `ui:repeat` with forms inside instead of a table?

Comment: Hi; the problem is that i have indeed a ui:repeat which generates elements (which have to be in unique forms to process ajax by update="@form"). now each element has a comment field, and all comments must be submitted by a button (for further processing). So i need a form for all the comment fields. and for each entry a single form for ajax-update

Comment: First of all you can't nest forms inside other forms. Isn't it easier to have everything in a general form and process only what you want?

Comment: yep, but the problem is, that if i execute the main form, some data is stored into the database. I need a "form" or something else to be able to switch the language of each entry one by one-->so one form each because of the problem mentioned above. so i need several forms which are like "gears"?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
<ui:repeat>
    <h:form>
         ...
    </h:form>
</ui:repeat>
```

instead of

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat>
         ...
    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Hi Balus; see attached pic. I need to perform update="@form" of only the red ones. thats the reason I need these seperate forms